# Interscholastic Mathematic League Senior B Division #1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let n be a positive integer less than 1000. If n^3 has 10 factors, compute the largest value of n.

Comment: ...and what have you tried doing?

Comment: I created a table from 1 to 10. Listing all of their third powers. When N equals 10 then 10^3 equals 1000. From their I tried to do prime factorization of the numbers in my table but still coudn't come up with the answer.

Comment: Note that $n$, not $n^3$, is less than $1000$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following result is useful in contests, and elsewhere. Let $p_1, p_2, \dots,p_k$ be *distinct* primes, let $e_1, e_2,\dots, e_k$ be positive integers, and let 
$$N=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}.$$
Then $N$ has
$$(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\cdots (e_k+1).$$
positive divisors. For example if $N=2^3\cdot 3 \cdot 5^2$, then $N$ has $(4)(2)(3)$ positive divisors.

Now we use the above result to answer the question.  Note that a cube has prime power decomposition of shape $p_1^{3a_1}p_2^{3a_2}\cdots p_k^{3a_k}$. If this cube has $10$ divisors, we have
$$(3a_1+1)(3a_2+1)\cdots(3a_k+1)=10.$$
 The only way this can happen is if $k=1$, and $a_1=3$. Thus  your number $n$ has the shape $p^3$ where $p$ is prime.  We want to find the largest prime $p$ such that $p^3<1000$. This prime is $7$, and therefore $n=7^3=343$.

**Comment:** Here is a brief informal proof of the key result. Imagine we are building a positive divisor $d$ of $N$. How many possible choices are there for the largest power of $p_1$ that divides $d$? That largest power  could  be any of $p_1^0$ (no $p_1$'s), $p_1^1$, and so on up to $p_1^{e_1}$, so we have $e_1+1$ choices.

For *every one* of these choices, we have $e_2+1$ choices for the highest power of $p_2$ that divides $d$, and therefore $(e_1+1)(e_2+1)$ ways to choose the largest power of $p_1$ that divides $d$ **and** the largest power of $p_2$ that divides $d$. But for every one of these choices, there are $d_3+1$ ways to choose the highest power of $p_3$ that divides $d$, and so on.

Comment: I have rarely used Number Theory and I still don't understand how to achieve my answer.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is 343. ;)

Comment: @Tayyeb Din: Yes, you got it. The result about the number of divisors (and the idea behind the proof) are useful additions to your problem-solving toolchest.

Comment: It's quite useful when solving computer problems too (e.g. [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)) - this formula often leads to more efficient methods for calculating the factors of a number.